# Issue with Jquery data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should save the x/y position of a canvas click to the canvas element as data attributes, but for some reason, they do not appear in the HTML when i inspect it with Chrome.

```
$('#canvas').click(function(e){
    $(this).data("pos-x", e.offsetX);
    $(this).data("pos-y", e.offsetY);
});
```

If i add a console log prior to this.data, the values are there, are they are not empty, what seems to be the issue?

It seems very straight forward, so i have a hard time seeing the problem.

Comment: Setting just the data value using data api doesnt create a data-* attribute for the dom element, use ``.attr` instead.

Comment: Why are you using `data-*` attributes in the first place?

Comment: @Ben: is there a reason not to?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes. In 99.9% of cases they violate separation of concerns. They're used to mix application presentation logic with business logic. Usually, at least from my anecdotal experience they stem either from lack of knowledge of other data structures or from not knowing about separation of concerns (and having a backing data model being the single source of truth for your presentation).

Comment: I have other events that need the x-y positions

Comment: @IvanRistic This sounds like bad architecture to me. Have a backing model for what the x and y positions _represent_ , share knowledge between application parts _explicitly_ and make the dependencies of each part of your application obvious.

Comment: Ever heard of variables? I hear they're pretty handy for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery reads from `data-` attributes, but `data('key', value)` doesn't modify element attributes. jQuery uses its own internal data store. If you actually want to add/change the `data-` attributes, use `attr()`:

```
$(this).attr("data-pos-x", e.offsetX);
$(this).attr("data-pos-y", e.offsetY);
```